# Parsear dados num arquivo que contém informações sobre o systeminfo

Tags: python-3.x

Foi gerado um arquivo "txt" contendo informações de retorno do comando `systeminfo`, e eu preciso conseguir copiar algumas das linhas do arquivo, no caso, as que contém informações sobre: memória física total, 
memória física disponível, memória virtual, tamanho máximo, disponível e em uso:

> Total Physical Memory:     16.282 MB 
>  Available Physical Memory:
>   10.111 MB 
>  Virtual Memory: Max Size:  18.714 MB 
>  Virtual Memory: Available: 10.798 MB 
>  Virtual Memory: In Use:    7.916 MB

Para obtenção do arquivo executei no prompt:
 <kbd>systeminfo > saida_systeminfo.txt</kbd>

**Segue código em desenvolvimento:**

```
archive_sysinfo = open('saida_systeminfo.txt', 'r')
text_sysinfo = archive_sysinfo.readlines()
lista_linhas2 = []
lista_info = []

for linha2 in text_sysinfo:
    lista_linhas2.append(linha2.split())
    print(linha2.split())

for linha2 in lista_linhas2:
    if "Mem¢ria" in linha2:
    lista_info.append(linha2[0:5])

lista_info = open("resultado_info.txt","w")
lista_info.write("Coletando dados de memoria")

string_info = ""
for j in range(0,7,1):
    string_info = lista_info[j][0] + " " + lista_info[j][1] + " " + 
lista_info[j][2] + " " + lista_info[j][3] + " " + lista_info[j][4] + "\n"
    print(string_info)
    lista_info.write(string_info)
```

Comment: Seria interessante você editar a resposta e adicionar um exemplo da estrutura do arquivo que você está lendo, senão não tem como saber onde a informação está ou como está guardada. Também seria produtivo explicar qual seria o resultado esperado e o quê não está dando certo. Especificar um pouco mais o que significa "Não consegui concluir o programa" para que outras pessoas tenham mais informações pra te ajudar.

Comment: está feito, vê se assim fica mais claro